# Libgdx and ProGuard not working with Themable Widget Library (Desktop)

Tags: java, libgdx, lwjgl, proguard

I am trying to obfuscate my Libgdx Java project with ProGuard, but I get an error at some point about the Themeable Widget Library at some point. This is for my Desktop project (not Android):

```
Ignoring unused library classes...
  Original number of library classes: 19830
  Final number of library classes:    880
Optimizing...
Unexpected error while evaluating instruction:
  Class       = [de/matthiasmann/twlthemeeditor/datamodel/Include]
  Method      = [addToXPP(Lde/matthiasmann/twlthemeeditor/datamodel/DomXPPParser;)V]
  Instruction = [6] invokevirtual #71
  Exception   = [java.lang.IllegalArgumentException] (Can't find common super class of [java/lang/Object] (with 0 known super classes) and [de/matthiasmann/twlthemeeditor/datamodel/Include] (with 1 known super classes))
Unexpected error while performing partial evaluation:
  Class       = [de/matthiasmann/twlthemeeditor/datamodel/Include]
  Method      = [addToXPP(Lde/matthiasmann/twlthemeeditor/datamodel/DomXPPParser;)V]
  Exception   = [java.lang.IllegalArgumentException] (Can't find common super class of [java/lang/Object] (with 0 known super classes) and [de/matthiasmann/twlthemeeditor/datamodel/Include] (with 1 known super classes))
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Can't find common super class of [java/lang/Object] (with 0 known super classes) and [de/matthiasmann/twlthemeeditor/datamodel/Include] (with 1 known super classes)
    at proguard.evaluation.value.ReferenceValue.generalize(ReferenceValue.java:344)
    at proguard.evaluation.value.ReferenceValue.generalize(ReferenceValue.java:481)
    at proguard.optimize.info.MethodOptimizationInfo.generalizeParameter(MethodOptimizationInfo.java:231)
    at proguard.optimize.evaluation.StoringInvocationUnit.generalizeMethodParameterValue(StoringInvocationUnit.java:176)
    at proguard.optimize.evaluation.StoringInvocationUnit.setMethodParameterValue(StoringInvocationUnit.java:112)
    at proguard.evaluation.BasicInvocationUnit.visitAnyMethodrefConstant(BasicInvocationUnit.java:223)
    at proguard.classfile.util.SimplifiedVisitor.visitMethodrefConstant(SimplifiedVisitor.java:204)
    at proguard.classfile.constant.MethodrefConstant.accept(MethodrefConstant.java:69)
    at proguard.classfile.ProgramClass.constantPoolEntryAccept(ProgramClass.java:453)
    at proguard.evaluation.BasicInvocationUnit.invokeMember(BasicInvocationUnit.java:178)
    at proguard.evaluation.Processor.visitConstantInstruction(Processor.java:573)
    at proguard.classfile.instruction.ConstantInstruction.accept(ConstantInstruction.java:157)
    at proguard.optimize.evaluation.PartialEvaluator.evaluateSingleInstructionBlock(PartialEvaluator.java:753)
    at proguard.optimize.evaluation.PartialEvaluator.evaluateInstructionBlock(PartialEvaluator.java:587)
    at proguard.optimize.evaluation.PartialEvaluator.evaluateInstructionBlockAndExceptionHandlers(PartialEvaluator.java:560)
    at proguard.optimize.evaluation.PartialEvaluator.visitCodeAttribute0(PartialEvaluator.java:264)
    at proguard.optimize.evaluation.PartialEvaluator.visitCodeAttribute(PartialEvaluator.java:181)
    at proguard.classfile.attribute.CodeAttribute.accept(CodeAttribute.java:101)
    at proguard.classfile.ProgramMethod.attributesAccept(ProgramMethod.java:79)
    at proguard.classfile.attribute.visitor.AllAttributeVisitor.visitProgramMember(AllAttributeVisitor.java:95)
    at proguard.classfile.util.SimplifiedVisitor.visitProgramMethod(SimplifiedVisitor.java:91)
    at proguard.classfile.ProgramMethod.accept(ProgramMethod.java:71)
    at proguard.classfile.ProgramClass.methodsAccept(ProgramClass.java:504)
    at proguard.classfile.visitor.AllMethodVisitor.visitProgramClass(AllMethodVisitor.java:47)
    at proguard.classfile.ProgramClass.accept(ProgramClass.java:346)
    at proguard.classfile.ClassPool.classesAccept(ClassPool.java:125)
    at proguard.optimize.Optimizer.execute(Optimizer.java:372)
    at proguard.ProGuard.optimize(ProGuard.java:307)
    at proguard.ProGuard.execute(ProGuard.java:116)
    at proguard.ProGuard.main(ProGuard.java:484)
```

This is how my ProGuard configuration file looks like:

```
-injars       ../Acast-desktop/bin/Acast.jar(!META-INF/MANIFEST.MF)
-outjars      ../Acast-desktop/bin/Acast-guarded.jar
-libraryjars  ../Acast/libs/gdx-sources.jar
-libraryjars  ../Acast/libs/gdx-controllers-desktop.jar
-libraryjars  ../Acast/libs/gdx-controllers-gwt.jar
-libraryjars  ../Acast/libs/gdx-controllers-android.jar
-libraryjars  ../Acast/libs/gdx-controllers.jar
-libraryjars  ../Acast/libs/gdx-controllers-desktop-natives.jar
-libraryjars  ../Acast/libs/gdx-tools.jar
-libraryjars  ../Acast/libs/gdx.jar
-libraryjars  ../Acast/libs/json-simple-1.1.1.jar
-libraryjars  ../Acast/libs/acast-network-commons.jar
-libraryjars  ../Acast-desktop/libs/gdx-backend-lwjgl.jar
-libraryjars  ../Acast-desktop/libs/gdx-backend-lwjgl-sources.jar
-libraryjars  ../Acast-desktop/libs/gdx-backend-lwjgl-natives.jar
-libraryjars  ../Acast-desktop/libs/gdx-natives.jar
-libraryjars  ../Acast-network-commons/libs/kryonet-2.18-all.jar
-libraryjars  <java.home>/../jre/lib/rt.jar

-optimizationpasses 1
-dontusemixedcaseclassnames
-dontskipnonpubliclibraryclasses
-dontpreverify
-verbose
-dontshrink
-optimizations !code/simplification/arithmetic,!field/*,!class/merging/*
-renamesourcefileattribute SourceFile
-keepattributes SourceFile,LineNumberTable

-keep public class * extends android.app.Activity
-keep public class * extends android.app.Application
-keep public class * extends android.app.Service
-keep public class * extends android.content.BroadcastReceiver
-keep public class * extends android.content.ContentProvider
-keep public class * extends android.app.backup.BackupAgentHelper
-keep public class * extends android.preference.Preference
-keep public class com.android.vending.licensing.ILicensingService
-keep class org.apache.**
-keep class de.matthiasmann.**
-keep class de.matthiasmann.twlthemeeditor.**
-keep class com.jcraft.**
-keep class com.badlogic.**
-keep class com.badlogic.gdx.**
-keep class com.badlogic.gdx.backends.**
-keep class com..badlogic.gdx.controllers.**
-keep class javax.**
-keep class org.lwjgl.**
-keep class org.lwjgl.opengl.**
-keep class com.badlogic.backends.**
-keep class * implements com.badlogic.gdx.utils.Json*
-keep class com.esotericsoftware.**
-keep class com.esotericsoftware.kryo.**
-keep class com.google.**
-keep class java.lang.reflect.**

-dontnote
-dontwarn de.matthiasmann.**
-dontwarn com.esotericsoftware.kryo.**
-dontwarn com.badlogic.gdx.**
-dontwarn org.lwjgl.**

-keepclasseswithmembernames class * {
  native <methods>;
}

-keepclasseswithmembers class * {
  public <init>(android.content.Context, android.util.AttributeSet);
}

-keepclasseswithmembers class * {
  public <init>(android.content.Context, android.util.AttributeSet, int);
}

-keepclassmembers class * extends android.app.Activity {
  public void *(android.view.View);
}

-keepclassmembers enum * {
  public static **[] values();
  public static ** valueOf(java.lang.String);
}

-keep class * implements android.os.Parcelable {
  public static final android.os.Parcelable$Creator *;
}

-keep public class com.pixelonion.acast.Main{
  public static void main(java.lang.String[]);
}
```

I don't understand the thrown exception. Did I miss to include a library jar? When I remove the line 'dontwarn de.matthiasmann.**' from my proguard config, I get errors like "can't find referenced class de.matthiasmann.twl.Widget". I am explicitly telling ProGuard to keep classes from libgdx and matthiasmann (The Widget Library: http://twl.l33tlabs.org/) so that they are not obfuscated (they are open source anyway).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was able to resolve the problem:

First off it's important to keep the line

```
-dontwarn de.matthiasmann.**
```

Then download the official library here: http://twl.l33tlabs.org/dist/TWL.jar

After that you add the library to the external libraryjars:

```
-libraryjars  ../Project/libs/TWL.jar
```

That's it. It will correctly obfuscate and optimize the code. I haven't tried running it yet, as I have run into another issue. But at least the error is gone now.